# How to print out word in one Arraylist also in another Arraylist in java

Tags: java, arraylist, words

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class PrintInstances {

public void handlewords() throws IOException {
    String path = "C:\\Users\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\src\\Wordlists.txt";
    String path1 = "C:\\Users\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\src\\sample.txt";
    ------handle the wordlist
    Features ft = new Features();
    String content = ft.readFile(path);
    String [] words = content.split(" ");
    int a = words.length;----wordlist
   -----handle the text file 
    StringBuffer bs = new StringBuffer();
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(path1);  
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    String line = null;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
      bs.append(line+"\n");
    }
      br.close();
      String str = bs.toString();
      String [] word = str.split(" ");
      int b = words.length;

     // List<String> uniqueWords = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>(words.length);
    List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>(word.length);


   /* for(int i=0;i<a;i++){
        boolean unique = true;
        for(int j=0;j<b;j++){
            if(words[i].equals(word[j])){
                unique = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(unique){
            uniqueWords.add(word[i]);
        }
    }

    for(String s: uniqueWords) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }*/


   for(String s: words){
        list1.add(s);
    }
      System.out.println(list1);

     for(String x: word){
        list2.add(x);
    }
      System.out.println(list2);

   for(String x : list1){
       for(String y: list2){
           if(y.contains(x))
               System.out.println(y);
       }
   }

}
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    PrintInstances pi = new PrintInstances();
    pi.handlewords();
}
}
```

I have tried to printout the same word in text file and also in the wordlist file, but after I put those in Arraylist, if I use `y.equals(x)`, nothings printed out. But if I used the contains to, more results came out, like student activate, activate,
One more question, can I get the index of word in text file if the word is also in wordlist?

Comment: If the words are unique (or if you don't care about it) it would be easier to use two sets to store the strings in...

Comment: could you show me an example? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a much more simple way to do that:

```
final Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(list1);
set.retainAll(list2);
```

Your set then only contains words which are in the two lists.

Note: if order matters, use a `LinkedHashSet` instead of a `HashSet`

Comment: Thank you, but when I was trying to printout the set, I got [],could you explain what happened?

Comment: Do you think the content on my text file is not correct? How to modify this? I read the content by code showing in the above

Comment: I fixed this problem, but one more question, how to index those specified words?

Comment: What do you mean by "index"?

Comment: I mean if the word in the text, I want to print the location of this word, like if the word "hello" is the fifth of the text(or in the arraylist),so I can get the result 5

Comment: Of which list? You have two here

Comment: I am sorry for confusing, I mean the word in the text file. The text arraylist

Comment: So, you want the line number in addition to the word itself? That changes matters...

Comment: I mean the location in the text file, like " I want to be superhero...." and the word "want" also appears in the wordlist, so I am going to find the location in text file, so the want should be labeled 1 in this case.